# How to wrap anchor around HTML on tinyMCE

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

Well I have this problem, I made a few custom buttons to the tinyMCE wordpress editor to insert html so the user wouldn't get confused with shortcodes. Everything works relativly ok... but there is a button that wraps a anchor to a div.

```
<a name="buton" class="prod-button" href="some-href">
  <div>
       ...
  </div>
</a>
```

The problem is that when the content is inserted into the editor, the ancho is erased.

It is not a problem of the button, but it how tinyMCE is configurated I believe, because it also happens when I write the html directly in the editor

I've already done this and it didn't work

```
tinyMCE.init({
    allow_html_in_named_anchor: true,
    valid_children: '+a[div],+a[span],+a[img]', 
    extended_valid_elements : "a[*]",
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the link with `<div>`, so like this:

```
<div>
  <a name="buton" class="prod-button" href="some-href">
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

There is no need of **allow_html_in_named_anchor**. Only **valid_children** is required.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best solution to insert the form is creating a short code. So, you can load the form into the sidebar and then use the short code to display the form content.

This the documentation
https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Regards.
Ed

Comment: Form? Sidebar? I don't know what you are talking about, but the whole idea is to avoid shortcodes, because they are not user friendly, and do not representate the actual content

Comment: Then I would recommended uses Visual Composer. It has all the functionalities that you need. https://vc.wpbakery.com/ Ed.